# How to check whether content entered by a user in a custom form is valid HTML?

Tags: 6, forms

I am trying to write a custom form in Drupal 6 which will check whether the content submitted by a user is valid HTML.

If the content is valid I need to generate a txt file with HTML markup based on the content without a DTD.

Comment: there's no reliable way to do that.  I don't often say it, but what you're trying to do would be virtually impossible.

you could try tying in to this: http://validator.w3.org/docs/api.html

but I just can't see this being easy at all.

Comment: I heard about a PHP library called Tidy which can check if your HTML is valid and I thought someone would know about that.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably do that with [PHPTidy](http://php.net/manual/en/book.tidy.php) (PHP Module) and [tidy_get_error_count](http://php.net/manual/en/function.tidy-error-count.php)